# Excel - Match two columns, add value from third column and also append the unmatched data

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have data in 2 tables. Both data tables have same field names since it contains billing of customers over 2 years. I need to create one table where I can compare past and current year. Hence first I need to match data of say 2016 with 2015 and get values from 2015 table in 2016. Also I need to append the unmatched values (those unmatched customers probably didn't do any billing in the current or past year). I was able to match and get values using vlookup but I culdn't append unmatched values (whose Ids are in the system but didn't do billing). Can anyone help?
Thank you.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwlxH.png)
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1orpE.png)
[Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzSFn.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please provide your formulas and some sample-data so we can run tests. You do not need to show any "real" data, just some samples (like `QWERTZ`, `abc` or `123`) which are used in the same way. Simply help us helping you :)

Comment: I am not able to add more than two tables. Anyway I have uploaded an example of two tables. In the final Table I need following fields (ID, Customer name, 2016Cutomerpay, 2015Customerpay).

Comment: Table 1 contains data of customers for year 2015 and table 2 contains data for customers for 2016. Customers in one table may or may not be in other table. Hence I need to combine all the data together so that I have 4 fields in the final table (ID, CustomerName, 2016customer_pay and 2015 Customer_pay).  (wherever the customer is in one table and not in another I still need to merge all data together. Customer_pay can have zero value if there was no billing in any of the year)I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sheet 3:

```
A2: =MIN(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A)
A3: =IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,">"&A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,">"&A2),MIN(IFERROR(SMALL(Sheet1!A:A,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<="&A2)+1),MAX(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A)),IFERROR(SMALL(Sheet2!A:A,COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,"<="&A2)+1),MAX(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A))),""))
'and copy A3 down
B2: =IF(A2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))))
C2: =IF(A2="","",SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!C:C))
D2: =IF(A2="","",SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!C:C))
'and copy B2:D2 down
```

should be what you want... if you have any questions, just ask...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I still didn't get the chance to verify it on my  data. I'll let you know soon how it went. Thank again for your time and patience. :-)